# Recreating KaTeX emulation in La/TeX?

Tags: package, tex, katex

I'm working on a site that is using KaTeX for rendering math. However, the interface for entering the math content is (really) not ideal, so it is actually faster for me to work in an editor, like Sublime Text 3 and import the work; however, an issue I run into is that when I import, I discover various functions / environments aren't supported (i.e. emulated) by KaTeX.

If it were just me working on the material, I would simply learn as I go and consult the KaTeX documentation page; however, I have several contractors working on digitizing content who do *not* have access to the site (and I don't have the ability to give them access), and so cannot learn by trial-and-error. Instead, I end up with piles of documents that all need to be manually adjusted, to render as desired with KaTeX.

As such, **I wanted to assemble a preamble for a LaTeX document that would recreate the abilities (i.e. functions and environments) KaTeX can emulate, and was wondering if such a preamble / package already exists?** I have tried a few quick searches, but because I'm looking for something that imitates an emulator, I'm finding it tricky to find the right choice of words to get relevant results.

I wasn't sure if this were best posted here or on the TeX.se - I suspect it falls in-between the two - so I apologize if my guess was wrong and I should've tried there first. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated, as this is creating a substantial bottle-neck in my workflow but is also just outside of my ability to solve on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Supported functions is one thing. To tackle that you might actually stand a fair chance of just tokenizing the input, looking for backslash name sequences and checking them against a list extracted from KaTeX sources to see which are supported.

I guess one could even try to remove all other functions from LaTeX. Or rather hide them, such that the user input can't access them but third party libraries can. Getting rid of language features (as opposed to macros) such as `\def` would probably be even harder. Better askn on the TeX stack exchange for details of you really want to follow this route.

As an alternative I guess you might be able to perform the check I described above in TeX. Write a macro which reads the current file as plain text instead of TeX source, to perform this analysis. Or some such. But a separate stand-alone tool would be much easier.

If you are going for a separate tool, you might as well write it in JavaScript for Node, and have it run KaTeX on the input. That way you can at least tell whether it will get typeset to *something* or error out.

Whether the rendering is what you expect from LaTeX may be another question. In general KaTeX aims to reproduce LaTeX behaviour, so any difference might indicate a bug. But bugs exist, so all of this might not avoid the need for checks. How about you just processing the math part of the input with KaTeX to some HTML which authors can check without access to the site?

As for existing tools or macro packages, I know of none, but tool or library questions are off topic on stack exchange anyway.